# Loops to update allocation

Tags: loops, count, sas

I have a data that goes like this:

```
 Subject  Treatment X 
 1            1     X12
 2            2     X12
 3            3     X13
 4            1     X11
 5            2     X13
 6            3     X12
 7            1     X11
 8            2     X12
 9            1     X11
 10           3     X13
```

I have to count the number of X's using the variable Z so Z11=#of X11's , Z12=#of X12's and so on but if the last number in the X and T is the same then you add one to the allocation.

So Z11=X11+1 if T=1, Z12=X12+1 If T=2 and Z13=X13+1 if T=3 but if last number and T's don't correspond to each other then it would stay the same Z11=X11, Z12=X12 and Z13=13. I am using proc sql to count the allocations but don't how to add 1 each time the loop goes through another subject.

```
proc sql;
create table new1 as select 
sum(y="X11")+1 as z11,
sum(y="X12") as z12,
 sum(y="X13") as z13
 from dynamic;
 quit;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You've asked this a few times now, I think. Please include the exact output expected from the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear exactly what you want, but I would do this in a data step creating the variables you want, and then sum up the totals.

```
data have;
input  Subject  Treatment X $;
datalines;
 1            1     X12
 2            2     X12
 3            3     X13
 4            1     X11
 5            2     X13
 6            3     X12
 7            1     X11
 8            2     X12
 9            1     X11
 10           3     X13
;

data have;
set have;
z11 = 0;
z12 = 0;
z13 = 0;
if x="X11" then do;
    z11 = z11 + 1;
    if Treatment=1 then
        z11 = z11+1;
end;
else if x="X12" then do;
    z12 = z12 + 1;
    if Treatment=2 then
        z12 = z12 + 1;
end; 
else if x="X13" then do;
    z13 = z13 + 1;
    if Treatment=3 then
        z13 = z13+1;
end;
run;

proc summary data=have;
var z:;
output out=want sum=;
run;
```

produces:

> ```
>                          _TYPE_    _FREQ_    z11    z12    z13
>
>                              0        10       6      6      5
> ```

You can drop the `_TYPE_` and `_FREQ_` variables if you need.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I have one more question that I need some help with. I need to find the standard deviation of each allocation so it would be: M1=std(z11,z12,z13) if Treatment=1, M2=std(z11,z12,z13) if Treatment=2 and M3=std(zz,z12,z13) if Treatment=3. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Rani please mark this as the answer if it answers your original question and post your new question as a new question.